# Is there a way to visualize the brackets when printing a Tensor with Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor, eigen3

Let's imagine that I create a Tensor of dimension 4 with Eigen.

```
    Eigen::Tensor<double,4> m(3,3,10,10);          //Initialize
    m.setRandom();     
    cout << m << endl;
```

When I display the Tensor, I will have lists of values but there will be no parentheses or brackets to better visualize the shape. Is it possible to Overloading operator<< on Eigen::Tensor to allow a better visualization?

Comment: Not yet, but hopefully soon: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/merge_requests/327

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small function, using the `chip` function recursively. You will need C++17 though as it uses the `if constexpr` construct. Here is the sample code, which is not tested for any expression other than `Eigen::Tensor` but should work as long as `chip` is supported by the expression.

```
template<typename Derived, typename... DimsType>
void PrintTensorNumpy(
  const Eigen::TensorBase<Derived, Eigen::ReadOnlyAccessors>& input, int dim0,
  DimsType... dims)
{
  constexpr size_t numDimensions = sizeof...(dims);
  if constexpr (numDimensions > 1)
  {
    std::cout << "[\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim0; i++)
    {
      PrintTensorNumpy(
        (static_cast<const Derived&>(input)).chip(i, 0), dims...);
    }
    std::cout << "]";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "[" << input << "]\n";
  }
}
```

The placement of the square brackets are still questionable but it serves the purpose, specially if you are using this for debugging.